# vb6 debugging .exe to .dll

Tags: vb6

Probably a question that has been asked before.  Please guide me to any questions that might answer my question...

I have a VB6 .exe that calls a **VB6** .dll.  I would like to debug the .dll from the .exe code.

Any ideas on how to achieve that?  It has been a very long time since I have played with vb6.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open both VB6 projects in one VB6 IDE (a VB Project Group ... creates and uses a file extension of .vbg if I remember correctly). Also, set debugging to Break in Class Module.

Comment: I tried that, do I have to unreference the .dll in the .exe?  If so, what do I reference in its place?

Comment: Geez ... it's been a while since I've done VB6. There should be a way to reference the .DLL project instead of the built file, just like in .NET. But like I said, it's been so long, I can't remember exactly.

Comment: that is exactly my problem too....  It has been a very long time, but now it seems I'm going to be using vb6  for awhile... :(

Comment: +1 As far as I can remember you reference the VBP not the DLL. See the tutorial from the VB6 manual for more details http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa733606(v=VS.60).aspx

Comment: @MarkJ - I'll try that when I get into the office.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, this is possible. You'll reference the DLL project in the VBG file (the project Group file, precursor the the newer "solution" file in Visual Studio).

Comment: it is weird..  I tried to follow the example, but when I try to run the project with both the .exe and the .dll I get a No creatable component detected...  I inherited this project so who I'm not that familiar with it yet.

Answer (score 4):

You need access to the DLL symbols (usually a PDB file). Make sure that the dll symbols are being generated.

If you open the dll as raw text and go to the end of the file, you can find the path where the pdb file is expected to be located.

Comment: I updated my question.  there was a typo.  I need to debug a vb6 .dll from within a vb6.exe.  Can you explain how to do this?

Comment: Do you mean a dll compiled with VB6 or The msvb6.dll (don't remember the exact name, but I mean the runtime)? in the former case, I think you need to do what I've answered.

Comment: I have 2 vb6 projects.  1 is a UI (.exe) and the other is a .dll project.  I have calls in my .exe to the .dll.  I want to be able to step into the .dll.

Comment: Ok, That's what I have understood from the beginning. That is perfectly possible and you shouldn't have to do anything special, but if it's not working the reason might be that your're not generating debug info for your dll OR that the dll pdb file is not accesible.

Comment: I guess my question is more about the pdb file...  do I attach to that file somehow?

Comment: The attaching is automatic, you don't have to do anything. Take a look at the output window when you debug the exe, does it say that the dll symbols were found?

Comment: I only see a intermediate and a watch window.  and when I'm running the .exe I'm seeing nothing in either

Comment: I don't think VB6 .DLLs generate .PDB files, do they?

Comment: It's usually easier to debug in the VB6 debugger, like Hardcode's answer. VB6 DLLs do create PDB symbols, but they are only necessary if you want to debug in a different debugger like WinDebug or Visual Studio 2010. Not usually necessary in a scenario where client and server are both VB6

Answer (score 3):

I think you have to add the dll project to the  to the exe project (File->Add project) to step into the dll code. 
Update:
Yes, I think you'll also need to remove the reference to compiled dll.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing a similar issue and I have been following all the steps you have provided. Nothing is moving. I'm not winning.

I think you have to add the dll project to the to the exe project (File->Add project) to step into the dll code.  You'll also need to remove the reference to compiled dll.

Comment: Reference is key here as Kabo Moleti points out.  With the exe and the DLL open in a vbg (group), when you go into the References for the exe project, you will see 2 entries that pertain to your DLL.  The additional one is a *project* reference.  It will show as a reference to the .vbp file, not the .dll.  Choose this reference when you are debugging.  When you run the debugger, and your exe invokes a DLL method, this reference to the project  tells the instruction pointer to go into your open code rather than the compiled DLL.  Change the reference back to the DLL when you finish debugging!

Comment: thanks MiloNC, yea i did exactly that but isnt going to my dll project. i used the breakpoints

Comment: Kabo Moleti.  My next suggestion, now that you have it configured, is to clear temp files.  This has saved me a bunch of times over the years when VB would occasionally behave strangely.  Close VB and all apps, reboot, go in File Explorer to the address %temp%, which will expand to C:\Users....\temp.  Delete all files.  The system will protect you from deleting any that are in use.  If you feel more cautious, look for ones that start with "VB" and others that have .tmp extension.  Then try again.