# Debugging DLL from the EXE project?

Tags: debugging, dll, vb6

I have a VB6 application that runs dependent on a DLL, to which both of them I hold the source code and are in separate vbp projects.

I know how to use breakpoint and run VB6 debug mode in the application project, but I want to know if it is possible to run debug mode for the DLL?

I saw this article http://www.ni.com/tutorial/4071/en/. Does it mean I first have to compile the application, then in the DLL project I start debug mode by invoking the compiled application and hook it to use the DLL from the project? what does the "TestStand" in the article mean?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Debugging VB6 dll from VB6 exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7972846/debugging-vb6-dll-from-vb6-exe)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open one of those 2 projects and add another (File - Add Project...) and then set your
application project as start up (project explorer, right click on application project).

[image]